What is the anime where the main character acquires a device that turns into a red wolf-like armor?
As the title suggests, I've been searching for an anime I wanted to watch when I was in elementary. I remember it was on Toonami. Its plot is based on mecha-like anime, and the main character accidentally acquires a device that turns into a suit with a wolf theme and aura in the background, similar to Power Rangers.
The main character had no helmet; instead, he had white headgear. His suit was red with some white from head to toe, and his hair color was also red. The anime features other characters who have similar devices to the main character. I only remember that two of them had a three-headed snake and a bird-like mecha.
There were five in total, including the main character, working for an organization to fight wild monsters (I don't remember whether they were also mechas or not). The five were somewhere in their teens or young adults.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Roughly what years were you in elementary school?

Male or female characters, was it set on a planet or in space, anything about the villains, was it a comedy or serious?

One of the Zoids cartoons? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iA3oHuVSqJM&list=PL4uKYCCHEsuqTy5zq87LI8uYIlFnjaAWd They were often shown on Toonami

Maybe D.I.C.E.? The main character has red hair and red armor with white, though there is a helmet and a dino theme as opposed to a wolf one. It was on Toonami during 2005. https://toonami.fandom.com/wiki/D.I.C.E.
